# Python List Initialisation with For Loop vs Multiplication

Tags: python, algorithm

Is there a difference in intialising a list using this

```
l = [0] * 20
```

compared to this

```
l = [0 for i in range(20)]
```

Under the hood, how does `[0] * 20` work compared to list comprehension in Python? The former method seems to result in faster runtime in LeetCode

Comment: For mutable objects, there is a big difference between them: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Ah, this answers it, thanks!